# Laravel package development

Tags: php, laravel, package, service-provider

I am trying to develop a Laravel package with a helper function, which returns a view. I have uploaded on GitHub already  https://github.com/faisalahsan/laravel-breadcrums. When I install it through Packagist  https://packagist.org/packages/faisalahsanse/laravel-breadcrums, it installs successfully, but when I register it in the provider array in my `app.php` as `Faisalahsanse\Breadcrums\BreadcumsServiceProvider::class,`. It gives the following error:

> Class 'Faisalahsanse\Breadcrums\BreadcumsServiceProvider' not found

I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong https://github.com/faisalahsan/laravel-breadcrums/blob/master/src/BreadcumsServiceProvider.php#L2

It should be **`Faisalahsan\LaravelBreadcrums`**. As this namespace you are adding in the **`composer.json`** file in **`psr-4`** autoload.

Also your provider to add will be **`Faisalahsan\Breadcrums\BreadcumsServiceProvider::class`**

Comment: thank your reply, I have made changes according your answer, e.g
same namespace in composer.json and breadcrumsserviceprovider file is `Faisalahsan\Breadcrums` and in my service provider array `Faisalahsan\Breadcrums\BreadcumsServiceProvider::class`, But giving same error. can you guide me?

Comment: it was my version error on packagist after your answer.
Thanks again.