# Laravel package development with dependacy package

Tags: php, laravel, package

### Background

I am new to the Laravel Package.

In my Laravel application I usually run the following command in order to install Bican Rokes, change the config files, etc...

```
php artisan make:auth 
php artisan migrate
```

### Objective

However, this process is tedious, so I was wondering if it is possible to create a package capable of automatizing the process.

### What I tried

To achieve this I read the Laravel documentation, which teaches how to create packages, but I was unable to understand if this is possible and if it yes, how it should be done.

### Questions

1. Can a package be used to automate this behaviour?
2. If yes, can you provide it?
3. If not, can you explain to me what a package really is? (links to tutorials are welcome)
4. If I cannot use a package, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172047/laravel-package-development

Comment: Not understand the question

Comment: @ Prashant. I need to create  like a batch file  which if I run takes care of all the changes and installation needed. I also need to give input in runtime like database name etc...

Comment: from my perspective, you have to run all laravel command manually

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a separate package should be created or not will depend on volume of work you want to accomplish. a starting point can be a custom console command, and from with-in that command, you can call multiple other commands.. And from their you can extend it to do other things like editing files etc. If you don't know how to write a console command in Laravel, here is the link to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 1):

I am not pushing the sale of anything, nor do I know this guy. But this tutorial is a pretty good starting point for laravel. 
[Laravel Tutorial Series](https://www.udemy.com/modern-web-development-with-laravel/)

Comment: Looks legit to me. kudos++ for being a new guy trying to help others !